# Send value from controller to controller

Tags: c#, controller

I have two controllers, each with a `Save` method.

```
public ActionResult SaveContract(Contract contract)
        {
          //code shortened for brevity
          int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@OBJECTID"].Value);
          return RedirectToAction("SaveContractDetails", "ContractDetails", id);
        }
```

and I am redirecting to `SaveContractDetails` method in `ContractDetails` controller. What I am trying to do is send the `id` of the `Contract` model to the `SaveContractDetails` method in the `ContractDetails` controller, like so:

```
public IActionResult SaveContractDetails(ContractSettlementDetail contractSettlementDetail, int id)
        {
          return View();
        }
```

The thing is, the `id` in the `SaveContractDetails` method is `0`. I suppose I can't send it the way I am trying to. I'd really want to avoid catching the `id` with javascript somehow and sending it to the method with an `ajax`. How should I proceed, any advice for this intern?

Comment: It's generally a bad practice to pass invoke controller actions like this. more so in separate controllers. [PRG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) is a valid case, but I don't think you're trying to achieve that. However, assuming you have a valid reason to do this, it seems ```SaveContractDetails``` needs two params(required) and you're only passing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send your route values this way => `new { id = id }` and it will work

```
public ActionResult SaveContract(Contract contract)
        {
          int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@OBJECTID"].Value);
          return RedirectToAction("SaveContractDetails", "ContractDetails", new { id = id });
        }
```